# R: Handling strings with a single or odd number of quotation marks

Tags: r, string

Consider the following string:

```
"><script>alert(1);</script>
```

I wish to assign this string (or a string like it) to an R variable.

If I try to do this the traditional way, such as:

```
x <- as.character("><script>alert(1);</script>)
```

the command fails due to the presence of the single quotation mark within the string itself. Is there a method to get round this complication without manipulating the string entirely?

It is important to keep the integrity of the string intact. For example, a method to get round this problem would be to change the quotation mark to an apostrophe, or to delete the quotation mark; but this is unacceptable.

Cheers

Comment: You can put it in single quotation marks: `x <- '"><script>alert(1);</script>'`. The double quotation mark will be escaped automatically with a backslash; but the string prints correctly if you use, e.g., `cat(x)`.

Comment: Note: `x <- as.character("><script>alert(1);</script>)`
is not failing due to the presence of the single quotation mark. It is failing because you used incorrect R syntax. The as.character() function requires either a pre-existing object name, like `as.character(mystring)` or it requires a string **contained in quotes**, like `as.character('"><script>alert(1);</script>')` or `as.character('this is an example')`. You can't just put in unquoted text.